# Using actionbartabs to display one fragment but differing data?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-tabs

I'm having a design issue. I'm not sure if this is a good way to do it but here is what I want to do.

I want a way for the user to quickly swipe or click on a button to change the data that is shown in a fragment which contains a list. I thought of using tabs but it seems that's more suited if you have different fragments for each tab and using only one fragment might not be best practices.

The reason I only want to use one fragment is because that code will not change for different tabs only the data that is given to the recyclerview.

Should I go forward with this or is there a better method?

Comment: You're right not to launch multiple fragments if it is only the dataset within the recycler that will change.

Comment: To initiate the dataset change, it depends on the number of unique datasets and it's a matter of personal preference - i.e. 2 datasets could have a simple button to switch it; 3-4 FAB menu, 5+ dropdown menu, swipe listeners could be used, etc. Tabs are generally used for unique fragments.

Comment: @McGuile Ok. So i have 3 datasets that they can view/edit. I guess FAB menu's would work well based off what you said. Thanks! Does this work with material design? And would it be clear to users that they can change datasets by clicking a FAB item?

Comment: Just because I said FAB menu for 3 items doesn't mean it's limited to that. There's a wide range of UI elements you could explore to perform the task. Good luck :)